# Is there a linux interface for arm cp15 register access?

Tags: linux, kernel, performance, arm, optimization

For performance optizimization I should be able to switch bits in `ACTLR` register of the `cp15` unit. I've done stuff like this before in bare metal projects, but from linux user space I can't execute mcr and mrc for good reason (privileged mode required). And I am aware that coprocessor register changes will have special implications in a multiuser environment.

So obviously I need a kernel interface to do such a thing, but no matter what term I look for in web search, I don't find anything like that.

Well, if nothing like this is implemented in any kernel module, do I have a chance at all besides from taking one of the arm cores away from my linux and have a bare metal job running there?

Comment: Why not write your own kernel module? There are example modules which you just have to modify a little bit.